# Why does Windows 10 no longer put focus on the most recently focused window when closing the focused window?

Tags: windows-10, window-focus

I'm a power keyboard user, and I commonly follow this pattern:

- Find a file in Windows Explorer, highlight it using all keystrokes, and hit "Enter" to open it for visual inspection.
- After inspecting its contents, hit Alt+F4 to close it.
- Use the keyboard to find the next file, etc.

That worked great until this recently.  For some reason, after I close the window where I'm inspecting the file, the focus doesn't return to the Windows Explorer window like it used to, and I have to hit Alt+Tab.  Does anyone know what changed and how I can put it back?  The program that opens the file is LibreOffice Calc.
After the Calc window closes, if I hit F11 (which should maximize the focused window), nothing happens, suggesting that no window has focus.  Bizarre...

Comment: The focus might be stolen by another program. Try the [Window Focus Logger](https://www.adminscope.com/downloads/window-focus-logger/), and use `WindowFocusLoggerGUI.exe`. If the focus ends up in the taskbar, then you'll see Explorer as the stealer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change must have been the result of a Windows update.  A short while later, the behavior reverted back (I assume they fixed it in a subsequent update) to where Explorer regained focus after the other program closed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1186915)

Comment: I am the author, I don't need clarification, and I think it does provide an answer.